# If $f(x)=\int_{3}^x \sqrt{1+t^3} dt$ Find $(f^{-1})'(0)$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

Consider the integral  $$f(x)=\int_{3}^x \sqrt{1+t^3} dt$$

Using Theorem 7 from my textbook which is $$\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$$

$f'(t)= \frac{2t^3}{2\sqrt{1+t^3}}$

$f^{-1}(t)=\sqrt[3]{t^2-1}$

I get confused here because does the integral affect how I should proceed or should I have incorporated the integral from the start?

Comment: Your derivative step is very wrong; a big red flag is the fact that you have a function of $x$ equal to a function of $t$.

Comment: It was a force of habit, i'm used to $f(x)$

Comment: It's still quite wrong. You've differentiated $\sqrt{1 + t^3}$, not $f$. You've also just changed where the notation is incorrect to the previous line!

Comment: Yeah so people like you don't comment on my tiny mistakes. I'm sleep deprived and over stressed, give me a break.

Comment: Look, I'm sorry if my comment came across as harsh, but I wasn't nitpicking a tiny mistake. By mixing up $t$ and $x$, you missed the fact that you need to differentiate an anti-derivative, and instead differentiated the wrong function.

Comment: Thank you for your input, if you would kindly make the changes you see it fit to correct the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The very first expression after “Consider the integral” is wrong: $f(t)$ should be $f(x)$. Also (here and in real life) I highly recommend that you don’t be rude to someone who’s trying to help you.

Comment: All I'm gonna say is you caught me at a bad time. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINTS:**

From the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have

$$f'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}$$

Moreover, note that

$$f(3)=0\implies f^{-1}(0)=3$$

Finally, the theorem from your text book reveals that

$$\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}=\frac1{\sqrt{1+(f^{-1}(x))^3}}$$

Comment: Is my inverse function correct though?

Comment: Hi Eric.  No, the inverse of $\int_3^x\sqrt{1+t^3}\,dt$ is not $\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}$ .